# How to destroy model from rake task in rails

Tags: model, ruby-on-rails-5

```
namespace :my_tasks do
  desc 'Destroy Unnecessary Models'
  task destroy_models: :environment do
    'rails d model Product'
    'rails d model Book'
  end
end
```

It's my rake task `namespace` file code. when I run `rails my_tasks:destroy_models` nothing to display any errors message. But models are not destroyed. Is there anything I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute shell command you have to use `sh` method

```
namespace :my_tasks do
  desc 'Destroy Unnecessary Models'
  task destroy_models: :environment do
    sh('rails d model Product')
    sh('rails d model Book')
  end
end
```